# Use request-specific context inside a global (singleton) service

Tags: node.js, express, nestjs, typeorm

I'd like to be able to log (as in `console.log`) the logged-in user for every SQL query being done. I'm using Nest.js and TypeORM (and it's wrapper for Nest.js). I couldn't figure out how to inject request-specific data into a global (singleton) provider.

I'm using Nest.js v6.6.3, and `@nestjs/typeorm` v6.1.3.

```js
// current-user.service.ts
@Injectable({ scope: Scope.REQUEST })
export class CurrentUserService {
  get currentUser(): string | null {
    if (!this.request || !this.request.user) {
      return null;
    }

    return this.request.user.email;
  }

  constructor(@Optional() @Inject(REQUEST) private request: Request) {}
}

// logger.service.ts
@Injectable()
export class LoggerService extends Logger {
  constructor(private readonly moduleRef: ModuleRef) {
    super();
  }

  log(message: any, context?: string) {
    super.log(this.formatMessage(message), context);
  }

  private formatMessage(message: any) {
    // ** This is the problematic code **
    const currentUserService = this.moduleRef.get(CurrentUserService, {
      strict: false,
    });
    return `[${currentUserService.currentUser}]: ${message}`;
  }
}

// typeorm-logger.service.ts
@Injectable()
export class TypeormLogger implements Logger {
  // Logger is imported from `typeorm`
  constructor(private logger: LoggerService) {}

  logQuery(query: string) {
    // there are more params, don't matter for the sake of the argument
    this.logger.log(query);
  }
}

// logger.module.ts
@Module({
  providers: [LoggerService, TypeormLogger],
  exports: [LoggerService, TypeormLogger],
})
export class LoggerModule {}

// app.module.ts
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.ForRootAsync({
      imports: [LoggerModule],
      inject: [TypeormLogger],
      useFactory: (typeormLogger: TypeormLogger) => {
        return {
          type: 'mysql',
          logger: typeormLogger,
          keepConnectionAlive: false,
          ...
        };
      },
    }),
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

It seems like using `moduleRef.get()` can't do cross-`Module` resolving, so I tried using `moduleRef.resolve()` instead, but then I still get `CurrentUserService` with a `request === undefined`. Furthermore, `resolve()` returns a `Promise`, which is not-ideal for a something like logging.

The above is a specific use-case, but can be generalized - if you have code that's not called directly from a Controller, you can't inject transient data like the authenticated user, or a request id (both useful for logging). This seems weird, especially since Nest.js relies heavily on IoC.

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm in the same boat.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up working around Nest.js, and it seems to work fine so far. Notice that we use it in an internal app, so we have a low concurrent user count, so YMMV.

The solution is based off of the `asyncctx` package, as suggested [here](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/699#issuecomment-405868782). You can find the full solution [here](https://gist.github.com/bengry/924a9b93c25d8a98bffdfc0a847f0dbe).

Comment: @AgentLiquid - see above

Answer (score 0):

**For anyone coming here in 2022:**
it seems the suggested approach by maintainers of NestJS is to use some kind of [CLS](https://dev.to/miketalbot/simplify-your-node-code-with-continuation-local-storage-variables-4b3k) (Continuation local storage) library.

The recommended library is https://github.com/Papooch/nestjs-cls

From the README:

> Some common use cases for CLS include:
>
> - **Tracing the Request ID and other metadata for logging purposes**
> - Making the Tenant ID available everywhere in multi-tenant apps
> - Globally setting an authentication level for the request

I agree that its very odd that this behaviour is not built in, but a quick search of closed issues:

https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/8625

And you will see multiple recommendations for this approach by maintainers

**Edit:** It seems OP's answer uses a CLS library as well, but not officially endorsed by NestJS. So maybe its better to use `nestjs-cls` instead.